# Proving a statement with two variables by complete induction

Tags: proof-writing, induction

I was recently introduced to this topic and I'm trying to prove Tue following statement.

For most of numbers, m^n => n^m

So I derived this into something that could be proved by induction... The other problem is I realized I have to work with m and n, and in the past I only worked with a single n for most of the proofs.

Can someone guide me?

By previously known facts m > 1 so in other words I have to prove that:

For all m, there exists a k such that for all n, if m >1 ^ n>= k) then m^n => n^m

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you want to prove (I think):

For all $m$, 
there exists a $k =k(m)$
 such that 
if $n>= k$ then 
$m^n \ge n^m$.

This is equivalent to
$m^{1/m} \ge n^{1/n}$.
But $x^{1/x}$
is decreasing for $x > e$.
(There are lots of proofs of that on this site.)

Therefore,
if $3 \le m < n$,
$n^{1/n} < m^{1/m}$.

Therefore,
if $m \ge 3$,
chosing $k(m) = m+1$
works.

If $m=2$,
$n > 4$ works,
since
$n^{1/n} < 4^{1/4}
= 2^{1/2}$.